# Exponent notation in siunitx

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, units

I would like to use numbers in `siunitx` where the main number and uncertainty have exponents like:

```
\num{1.1e-2\pm0.1e-2}
```

However this gives a Misplaced sign token error and I have to first find a common exponent for both quantities and write the exponent in the end:

```
\num{1.1\pm0.1e-2}
```

This gives the expected output of 1.1(1) x 10^{-2}.

Is there any configuration option to make the syntax in the first example, or perhaps something with different exponents like `\num{1.1e-2\pm1e-3}`, equivalent to `\num{1.1\pm0.1e-2}`?

Comment: `siunitx` may be instructed to use a specific exponent. If it read value and uncertainty with exponents, it could surely produce what you want, but doesn't do at the moment.

Comment: @Toscho I would like to be able to specify the format like 1.1(1)e+1 and use exponents for the input number and uncertainty.

Comment: I think, this is a bug. Please report it to @Joseph Wright.

Comment: @HenriMenke I have submitted a bug report in the siunitx github site

Comment: This is rather a missing feature than a bug. Uncertainties can only be given with the same exponent as the number.

Comment: I think `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num[separate-uncertainty=true]{6.9(02)e-2}
\end{document}` is what you are looking for (assuming I haven't misunderstood your question).

Answer (score 2):

This is 'status-bydesign': the format used by `siunitx` for numbers allows for only one exponent. The logic is that a number and it's uncertainly should necessaries have the same exponent, and thus giving two exponents is an error. Adding more flexibility to the current parser is not a realistic option, both for complexity and speed reasons.

There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/208) for 'plugable' approach to parsing numbers: I am committed to doing this in principle but currently have no time frame on it (far from trivial work, of which I have lots!).

Comment: If the format of the number is defined with an option like `table-format` would it be feasible to allow the number and uncertainty to have different exponents?